# Private Message Database Design

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

Alright, so I think I'm pretty close to having what I need, but I'm unsure about a couple of things:

```
TABLE messages

message_id
message_type
sender_id
timestamp

TABLE message_type

message_type_code (1, 2, 3)
name (global, company, personal)

TABLE message_to_user

message_id
receiver_id
status (read/unread)
```

Goals:

1. Be able to send GLOBAL messages to all users.
2. Send PERSONAL messages between 1 or more users.
3. Determine if any of these messages have been read or not by the the receiver.

Questions:

1. Does my schema take care of all that it needs to?
2. What would a sample SQL query look like to populate someones inbox, bringing in GLOBAL messages as well as PERSONAL messages - I'd like to be able to determine which is which for the UI.

And please feel free to add to my schema if you feel it would benefit.

Comment: Could you explain what the three tables hold. I have guessed the messages one, but message_type and message_to_user I'm not 100%

Comment: Have suggested a few tweaks below, if any of them suit you I'll add to SQL code to them. If not, I shall let the brain cogs rest :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Schema looks like it will work.  Should probably have a Created date too.  There's no way to know if you've read a global message though without creating entries for everyone.

Here's some SQL:

```
SELECT M.*, MTU.* 
FROM messages M 
    LEFT JOIN message_to_user MTU ON MTU.message_id=M.message_id
WHERE MTU.receiver_id={$UserID} OR M.message_type={$GlobalType}
ORDER BY M.created_on DESC
```

[EDIT]
Problem: Every user needs to have their own unique "read" status for global e-mails.  You probably also want to give them the ability to "delete"/hide this e-mail so they don't have to be looking at it all the time.  There is no way around this without creating either a row for each e-mail as it's going out, which is probably taxing to do that many INSERTS all at once...or better yet, don't create a status until it's read.  This way, INSERTS for global e-mails will only occur when the message is read.

```
messages
    message_id
    message_type
    sender_id
    timestamp

message_recipient
    message_id
    user_id

message_status
    message_status_id
    message_id
    user_id
    is_read
    read_datetime
    is_deleted
    deleted_datetime

SELECT M.*, MR.*, MS.*
FROM messages M
    LEFT JOIN message_recipient MR ON MR.message_id=M.message_id
    LEFT JOIN message_status MS ON MS.message_id=M.message_id
WHERE 
    (MS.message_status_id IS NULL OR MS.is_deleted = 0)
    (MR.user_id={$UserId} OR M.message_type={$GlobalType})
ORDER BY M.timestamp DESC
```

[EDIT]
Whether to use message_type as a DB table or simply as settings within your code is partly a personal preference and partly your needs.  If you need to query the DB and see the text "personal" and "global" directly from your query, then you want to use the message_type table.  However, if you only need the "type" to handle your business logic, but don't need to see it in query results, then I would go with an "Enum" style approach.  Enums are a C# thing...in PHP, the closest you've got is a class with constants...something like:

```
class MessageTypes {
    public const Global   = 0;
    public const Personal = 1;
}
```

So, your query would be: `WHERE ... message_type=".MessageTypes::Global."...`

Comment: I edited some of the tables above^^ ... So there's no way to be able to effectively display whether or not a global message has been read or not... say if the user signs in a reads the global message?

Comment: Sure there is. Create a "global read" table with columns for user and message id. Add a left join on message id and user, and then check for one of those fields on the global read to be null. That will return null for any message that isn't global or the user hasn't read.

Comment: Nice, but I don't think he'd need to check whether the message was global or not. If it's a global message, there will simply be multiple recipient IDs for it (meaning it'll appear more than once in the messages_to_users table). Selecting by recipient should be adequate.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean you can't do it...just that the schema above wouldn't do it without creating a message_to_user marked as "read" for each user for a global message.  Or as Tyler suggested, creating another table...but then I would say only use one table for read status...don't break it into two or you're making it overly complex.

Comment: lunchmeat...by his schema, I was assuming he didn't want to create a row for every single user.  If he does, then it solves all the problems I mentioned, but creates a lot of INSERTs.

Comment: No, I don't want to create a row for every user just because it's a global message. There must be a nice clean way to handling this.

Comment: So, it's impossible to make a unique "read" status for each user without creating a row for each user somewhere.  I've updated my answer with my next suggestion.

Comment: Kevin, I very much appreciate your time on this. Can you take a look at LethalMango's answer below and tell me what you think?

Comment: LethalMango said it himself, the DB schema he has isn't normalized, which I generally steer clear of.  However, his single-table schema is simplistic to use.  If you're looking for the lowest level of complexity, then the single table might work for you.  If you're looking for scalability, stick to a normalized DB.  His multi-table schema, however, seems to add complexity over what I put above.  With his multi-table schema you handle PMS differently depending on type, whereas with my schema, they would be handled the same while still being normalized.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That makes sense. I think I'll go with your approach.

Comment: Also, in the tables above are you suggesting that `message_type` does not need to be it's own table?

Comment: up to you on message_type.  I added an explanation of an alternative approach to my answer above.

Comment: Using the one table design as I said would take it out of 3rd form normalisation, splitting the `message_type` from the `message_tbl` would then normalise it again. I added both examples for choice.. whatever works for you dcolumbus. Happy coding

Comment: As far as "looping" over the users and INSERT for a global message, is that something that I should do or is there another approach?

Comment: Given the schema I placed above, you do not need to create more than one message for any PM.  You also would NOT create a message_status until AFTER they've read or deleted the message.  So, no looping for global messages.  For messages to 1 or more users in a personal message, you would have to loop through and create message_recipient rows for each recipient.

Answer (score 5):

The one method can be to separate the global messages from the personal messages as I think you have tried to do already.

To effectively get a read status for a global message, you would need to add a table with a composite key containing the global_message_id and user_id together.

```
messages_tbl
 - message_id    |  int(11)  | Primary Key / Auto_Increment
 - message_type  |  int(11)
 - sender_id     |  int(11)  | FK to sender
 - receiver_id   |  int(11)  | FK to receiver
 - status        |  int(1)   | 0/1 for Unread / Read
 - message       |  text
 - date          |  datetime

global_message_tbl
 - g_message_id   |  int(11)  | Primary Key / Auto_Increment
 - g_message_type |  int(11)
 - sender_id      |  int(11)  | FK to sender
 - date           |  datetime

global_readstatus_tbl
 - user_id       |  int(11)   | Primary Key
 - g_message_id  |  int(11)   | Primary Key
 - date          |  datetime
```

Alternatively merge the `messages_tbl` and `global_message_tbl` so they each user is sent a global message personally in a loop. This reduces your schema right down to one table.

```
messages_tbl
 - message_id    |  int(11)     | Primary Key / Auto_Increment
 - sender_id     |  int(11)     | FK to sender
 - receiver_id   |  int(11)     | FK to receiver
 - status        |  int(1)      | 0/1 for Unread / Read
 - message_type  |  varchar(8)  | Personal / Global / Company
 - message       |  text
 - date          |  datetime
 - type          |  varchar(8)
```

If you want the ability to normalise your table a bit better, and make it easier to add message types in the future, move message_type back into its own table again, and make `message_type` a FK of the `message_type_id`

```
message_type_tbl
 - message_type_id  |  int(11)    | Primary Key / Auto_Increment
 - message_type     |  varchar(8) | Personal / Global / Company
```

**Update - Sample Table (1 Table)**

`message_tbl`

```
message_id | message_type | sender_id | receiver_id |  status  |  message  |      datetime
    1      |   personal   |     2     |      3      |   read   |  foobar   |  12/04/11 00:09:00
    2      |   personal   |     2     |      4      |  unread  |  foobar   |  12/04/11 00:09:00
    3      |   personal   |     3     |      2      |  unread  |  barfoo   |  12/04/11 02:05:00
    4      |   global     |     1     |      2      |  unread  |  gmessage |  13/04/11 17:05:00
    5      |   global     |     1     |      3      |  unread  |  gmessage |  13/04/11 17:05:00
    6      |   global     |     1     |      4      |   read   |  gmessage |  13/04/11 17:05:00
```

`user_tbl`

```
 user_id  |  name
    1     |  Admin
    2     |  johnsmith
    3     |  mjordan
    4     |  spippen
```

The above assumes users 2, 3 and 4 are general users sending messages to each other, user 1 is the admin account that will be used to send global messages (delivered directly to each user individually) allowing you to see the same information as if it were a personal message.

To send a global message in this format you would simply loop over the users table to obtain all the ID's you want to send the global message out to, then simply `INSERT` the rows for each user in the `messages_tbl`.

If you don't anticipate your users sending millions of messages a day as well as regular global messages to millions of users then the number of rows shouldn't be an issue. You can always purge old read messages from users by creating a cleanup script.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I should clarify exactly what I'm trying to accomplish: personal messages (one to many), global messages sent from whoever has the permission to do so (one to many). And I want to be able to track whether or not the receiver has read any of these messages or not for the sake of the UI.

Comment: Also, are you suggesting that if it were all in one `messages_tbl`, there would be a row created for each person within the "conversation"? So, if **johnsmith** sent a message to **mjordan** and **spippen**, 3 records would be created? **mjordan** and **spippen** will both be receivers. For every individual user part of a conversation, there would be a row dedicated to them? I think I'm confusing myself...

Comment: @dcolumbus - I've updated my answer to include a sample table above, hopefully it clears a little bit up

Comment: LethalMango, this looks really good... and correct me if I'm wrong, but by storing so much of the information in one table really lessens the load on the database because it can be indexed? Almost every query will be on that one table... SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, correct?

Comment: @dcolumbus - with the schema as suggested above you are able to index the columns as required which is the main key in lowering resources. Depending on how many messages you are planning on sending/storing, the difference between storing it on multiple tables and in one would be nominal. Codewise, you would only be using one `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement which will reduce load very slightly.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help! I'm going to try both versions and see what I like best.

Comment: No worries - anything more just comment back :)

Comment: @lethalMango in the `message_tbl` if two people are in a convo, as in text messaging, what would be the `SELECT query to the database to select the convo between those two people?

Comment: @RobertRocha If you were only ever having a single chat history between them, `SELECT * FROM message_tbl WHERE (sender_id IN (1,2)) OR (receiver_id IN (1,2))`. If you wanted threaded message chats you'd need an additional table which had the thread information (ID / subject) and then use a FK in the message_tbl to link them together